# Should I reject a documentation change because of typos?

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues, typographical-error

I just came across a proposed documentation change that added a new section to a "useful redirection" topic.

It was 6 lines long and I would probably have accepted it had it not been for its title: "If http, than https".

Even though the content was relevant, I felt awkward introducing an obvious typo in the documentation and I did not find a way to edit the proposal.

While hesitating I realized it was a dupe and rejected it, but otherwise what would have been the correct response here?

Comment: Are you talking about http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/95465? Because I wanted to comment that it looked like a dupe but it was already accepted. I don't see your reject vote, though.

Comment: And that particular post had more grammatical issues than the typo you mentioned.

Comment: @HermannDöppes Yes, it is this one. It must have been accepted while I was on still deciding, because I did click on reject and linked the dupe as well. I know there were more typos (notice the 's' in the title) but I did not feel that adding a comprehensive list was relevant for my question.

Comment: Eh, you're probably right about the comprehensive list. But I still feel there might be a difference between introducing a single typo vs. a dozen grammatical errors. (Mainly it was me doubting we got the same question, though.)

Comment: “A dozen grammatical errors” being a slight exaggeration in this case, of course. Would be kinda hard to do on 25 words, after all.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion the best option is to comment on the proposed change and explain that it contains typos. The author of that proposed change can then fix it and resubmit the proposed change.

Other option is to approve it, and after it gets approved by others too, submit your own proposed change which fixes these typos.

Comment: Or we could finally get the “Approve and Edit” feature everyone is asking for. (=

Comment: Also that suggestion has a serious problem: Currently changes are approved faster than I can type a comment. I'm already happy if I manage to google for plagiarism before the change is approved.